# Function to encode object to string only if it is an unicode object

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, type-conversion

I need a simple function that receives a text object (that may be either a string or an unicode) and encodes it into a particular encoding, bu only if it is an unicode object, other else returns the original object. The function would always return a string object (assuming it would only receive a string or an unicode)

I came up with the following solution:

```
def encode_text(text, encoding="utf-8"):
    if isinstance(text, unicode):
        return text.encode(encoding)
    else:
        return text
```

But I'm wondering if there is a built-in python function that already does something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have such a function.

You should ask yourself why you need a function that does this. When data comes into your application, you should know whether it's bytes or Unicode so you should convert it at the source of where the data comes from. This means you can use Unicode throughout your application and you can encode it back to bytes when the data is leaving your application.

It is, of course, easy to have such a utility function but I'm wondering why the application is structured that you need to do this.

Comment: Actually this helper function would be used at the beginning of the main function of a library. I'm doing that to facilitate the life of the users of the library, so they could provide either strings or unicode objects. Inside the function I handle only strings, since I will be working at the byte level.

Comment: @GabrielMagno: ah ok, I thought this function was used at places in your application where data leaves the system. That would mean you're handling bytes / Unicode inconsistently throughout the application but it seems your application is bytes internally.